# Как решить задачу с верхним регистром

Tags: php

Например, имеется такой текст:

```
$text = "Text_text-text";
```

Нужно убрать символы и пробелы - для этого делаю так:

```
str_replace(array('_', '-', '.', ' '), '', trim($text))
```

> Результат: Texttexttext

Как сделать так, чтобы получили все тексты с верхним регистром?

> Например: TextTextText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I. Вариант*

1. С помощю разделителей (`split` или `regexp`) разбить строку с массив
2. в массиве изменит реестр всех первых букв.
3. Собрать все нужные элементы массива в строку

*II. Вариант*

думаю алгоритм такой

1. `$resultat = '';` сюда будем собирать строку. `FLAG = FALSE` нужно для реестра
2. Пройтись по строке по символам
3. Если `FLAG = TRUE` меняем реестр символа на верный
4. Если символ лежит в `array('_', '-', '.', ' ')`

   - 4.1. поставить `FLAG = TRUE` и не сохранять этот символ
   - 4.2. Если нет сохранить символ в `$resultat .= <символ>`

результат в `$resultat`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения из Doctrine Inflector

```
str_replace(" ", "", ucwords(strtr($word, "_-", "  ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для PHP 5.3 и выше и текста в кодировке UTF-8 можно использовать [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) с анонимной функцией:

```
$text = "Text_text-..text.привет мир!   ";

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '%([_\-\. ]+)(\p{L})?%u',
    function ($matches) {
       return isset($matches[2]) ?  mb_strtoupper($matches[2], 'UTF-8') : '';
    },
    $text
);

var_dump($text);
```

Результат

```
string(31) "TextTextTextПриветМир!"
```